# コメント一覧でコメントに対するコメントが正しく表示される記述方法をお教え願います。

Tags: php, smarty

お世話になります。どうかご教授頂けませんでしょうか。
サイト作成で、商品に関するコメント一覧ページを作成しております。その一覧で、ある商品のコメントに対する返信、つまりコメントに対するコメント（子コメント）を以下の様にコメントA（親コメント）の下に延々と表示できるようにしたいのですが、現在の状況はその下の様な状況になっており、同じコメントAが重複されます。

・期待する表示

```
コメントA
   コメントAに対するコメントa1
       コメントAに対するコメントa2
       コメントAに対するコメントa3
       コメントAに対するコメントa4

コメントB
       ………………………………………
       ……………………………………….
コメントC
       ………………………………………
       ……………………………………….
```

・   現在の表示

```
コメントA
      コメントAに対するコメントa1
コメントA
      コメントAに対するコメントa2
コメントA
      コメントAに対するコメントa3
コメントA
      コメントAに対するコメントa4

コメントB
       ………………………………………
       ……………………………………….
コメントC
       ………………………………………
       ……………………………………….
```

以下は以上の設定の必要最小限を記載したDB、PHP、Smartyでの記述でございます。問題点は何かをご指摘いただけませんでしょうか。あるいはこのようなケースの場合、どのような設定にするのが最適かご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

DB

```
親コメント用テーブル（dtb_review）     
review_id                              
product_id                              
reviewer_name                         
Comment                                                          
Create_date

子コメント用テーブル（dtb_review2）
review_id
original_review_id
reviewer_name
comment
Create_date

*dtb_reviewのreview_idとdtb_review2のoriginal_review_idは同じid（番号）です。
```

PHP

```
$col = "t1.review_id, t1.comment, t1.del_flg, t1.create_date, t1.product_id, t1.reviewer_name, t2.product_id, t5.original_review_id, t5.comment2, t5.reviewer_name, t5.create_date";

$from = "dtb_review as t1 
left join dtb_products as t2 using (product_id)
left join dtb_review2 as t5 ON t1.review_id = t5.original_review_id";

$where = " t1.del_flg = 0 ORDER BY t1.create_date DESC";

$this->arrReview = $objQuery->select($col, $from, $where, $arrval);
```

Smarty

```
{section name=cnt loop=$arrReview}

{$arrReview[cnt].comment|h|nl2br}（親コメント）

{if $arrReview[cnt].review_id|h == $arrReview[cnt].original_review_id|h }

{section2 name=cnt loop=$arrReview}

{$arrReview[cnt].comment2|h|nl2br}（子コメント）

{/section2}

{else}
{/if}

{/section}
```

*あるコメントに対してコメントされると、つまり親コメントに対して子コメントが作成されるとdtb_reviewのreview_idがdtb_review2のoriginal_review_idに渡ります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

親コメント、子コメントとそれぞれテーブルを分けていることで分かりにくくなっているのではないでしょうか？
このケースの場合、dtb_reviewと、productテーブルのみで実装可能です。

```
//reviewテーブル
review_id 
parent_review_id //親コメントの場合はNULL, 子コメントの場合は親のreview_id                             
product_id                              
reviewer_name                         
comment                                                          
create_date
```

parent_review_idには、親コメントの場合はNULL,子コメントの場合は親コメントのreview_idが挿入されるようにします。(サンプル内dtb_review2のoriginal_review_idのような役割です)

sql

```
SELECT
  t1.review_id,
  t1.parent_review_id,
  t1.comment,
  t1.del_flag,
  t1.create_date,
  t1.product_id,
  t1.reviewer_name,
  t2.product_id,
  CASE WHEN t1.parent_review_id IS NULL THEN t1.review_id ELSE t1.parent_review_id END as root_review_id
FROM dtb_review AS t1
  LEFT JOIN dtb_products AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
WHERE t1.del_flag = 0 ORDER BY root_review_id;
```

CASE .... AS root_review_id の箇所では、親コメントなら自身のreview_id,子コメントなら親コメントのreview_idを取得して、このroot_review_id を利用してORDER BY しています。

このようにすることで、
コメントA
コメントAの返信a
コメントAの返信b
コメントAの返信c
コメントB
・
・
・
といった順番で取得できるようになりますので、あとはテンプレートループ内でparent_review_idの値によって親コメントか、子コメントかを判別して出力するといった形が最善でしょう。

```
<dl>
{section name=cnt loop=$arrReview}
    {if $arrReview[cnt].parent_review_id == null} {* 親コメント parent_review_idがnullかチェック *}
        <dt>親コメント</dt>
    {else}
        <dd>子コメント</dd>
    {/if}
{/section}
</dl>
```

---

### 更新

親コメントの書き込み時間が新しい順にSQLを修正してみます。

SQL

```
SELECT
  t1.review_id,
  t1.parent_review_id,
  t1.comment,
  t1.del_flag,
  t1.create_date,
  t1.product_id,
  t1.reviewer_name,
  t2.product_id,  
  t3.create_date, //親コメントの作成日時
  CASE WHEN t1.parent_review_id IS NULL THEN t1.review_id ELSE t1.parent_review_id END as root_review_id
FROM review AS t1
  LEFT JOIN product AS t2 ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
  LEFT JOIN review as t3 ON ( CASE WHEN t1.parent_review_id IS NULL THEN t1.review_id ELSE t1.parent_review_id END ) = t3.review_id
WHERE t1.del_flag = 0 
ORDER BY t3.create_date DESC, t1.create_date ASC;
```

新たにLEFT JOIN句を追加しました。
これはparent_review_idを元に同じreviewテーブルをJOINし、親コメントの作成日時で並び替えを行っています。

並び替えの優先順序は

1. 親コメントの作成日時(降順)
2. 子コメントの作成日時(昇順)

これでご希望の動作になるかと思います。

Comment: Ke Na様
ご教授頂きまして大変感謝いたします。
まず、CASEの最後の箇所は次の様にroot_review_id で宜しいのですよね。
CASE WHEN t1.parent_review_id IS NULL THEN t1.review_id ELSE t1.parent_review_id END as root_review_id　また、＊＊テンプレートでの設定をご教授いただけませんでしょうか。＊＊ php側からはエラーは出ないのですが、テンプレートでの設定に問題があるらしく、出力結果で前回同様Aが重複されて（名前だけで、親コメントは表示されない）表示されてしまいます。（データの作りは子コメントに以下が挿入されています。review_id、parent_review_id、product_id、comment、create_date、reviewer_name、del_flag、親コメントは以上からparent_review_idを除いた全てにデータが挿入されています。）

Comment: おっしゃる通り、sorted_review_idではなくparent_review_idです。訂正しました。

また、簡潔ですがテンプレート追加しました。
IFステートメントで親コメントかサブコメントかを判別して出力しています。

Comment: Ke Na様
期待通りの表示になりました。ただ、ORDER BYの設定変更により、親コメントの投稿の古い順に表示されるようになりました。次の様にいろいろと調べたりしておりますが、降順設定ができません。
ORDER BY root_review_id, t1.create_date DESC

本件の場合の様にroot_review_idを利用したうえでの降順設定に関して何か対処作はございますでしょうか。

Comment: ＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊　Ke Na様、ご多忙の中恐縮でございます。コメント一覧＝絶対的に降順設定であり、昇順設定のコメント一覧は存在し得ないと思うのですが、本件の場合、どこかに設定のし忘れがない限り、phpのプログラムの欠陥ということになるのでしょうか。（恐らく同様のケースで降順設定のコメント一覧を作成されていると推察しておりますので、何が問題かアドバイスを頂けませんでしょうか。）　　＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊

Comment: 御連絡遅くなりました。
更新部分を御確認ください。読み解いていただくと動作が理解できるかと思います。

Comment: Ke Na様、 期待通りの出力結果になりました。本当に感謝いたします。状況によってはコメント一覧の昇順設定もありますね。昇順設定は存在し得ないなどと書いてしまい大変申し訳ございませんでした。ご指摘のように親コメントがほぼ無限で、子コメントが限定されるような場合は頂きました設定の様に親コメント（降順）、子コメント（昇順）が最適なのですね。もしかしましたら、本件の様なケースを以前扱った経験がなく、単に頭脳明晰な方だけなのかもしれませんが、貴重なお時間に懇切丁寧にご教授頂きまして感謝の限りでございます。

Comment: @baseballjapan 解決したようでしたら解決した回答を承認して下さい。